# Finding matching rows across columns and populating a separate column

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, excel, reclassify

I am trying to write a script that recategorizes 70 attributes in to 1 of 5 attributes.

I have two tables, each with two columns that I am focusing on. The first table has one column with 20k rows that all contain 1 of the 70 strings.

The second table is the key used as a key. The first column has 70 rows, each listing one attribute type. The second column tells what that attribute converts in to. There are 5 options, so each of the 70 will fall in to one of those five.

What I need to script to do is read through the key one row at a time, then find all matching rows in the other table's column. For all of those matches, a second column in the original table needs to be populated with the corresponding attribute (from the 5 options).

I have trouble explaining this, but it is really just recategorizing 70 attributes into 5 attributes. These are all strings. The original table is a layer in ArcMap, and the key table is an excel file. I am not sure how to write this script.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import xlrd
from xlrd import open_workbook

xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(conversion_table)
xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols   # Number of columns
for row_idx in range(0, xl_sheet.nrows):    # Iterate through rows
    print ('-'*40)
    print ('Row: %s' % row_idx)   # Print row number
for col_idx in range(0, num_cols):  # Iterate through columns
    cell_obj = xl_sheet.cell(row_idx, col_idx)  # Get cell object by row, col
    print ('Column: [%s] cell_obj: [%s]' % (col_idx, cell_obj))

# print water land use category column
conversion_column = xl_sheet.col(0)
list1 = list()
list1.append(conversion_column)
print list1


# print land use field from roadway
fc = original_table
field = "LAND_USE"
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
row = cursor.next()
list2 = list()
while row:
    results = (row.getValue(field))
    list2.append(results)
    row = cursor.next()
print list2
```

I'm using version 10.3.1.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 10.3.1

Comment: In that case I recommend investigating the newer data access cursors, Excel to Table tool and Python list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a lot easier to just do it by hand, but it needs to be a script  so that when other people update the excel file they can click to run the script and update the layer. They might add/change attributes later on.

Comment: The functions I recommended are what I would use to write that short script.

Comment: Oh sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) is essential for this task. First create a dictionary of all your keys and their associated new values. Then use an `UpdateCursor` to update your table.

Something like this:

```
##the table to be updated
updateTab = r"C:\path\to\updateTable"
#the field name of the field containing the values to convert
updateTabValFld = "ValueFieldName"
#the field name of the field that will be populated with the new values
updateTabUpdateFld = "UpdateFieldName"

##the table with the keys
keyTab = r"C:\path\to\keyTable"
#key table key field name
keyTabKeyFld = "KeyFieldName"
#key table value field name
keyTabValFld = "UpdateValueFieldName"


#-------

import arcpy

#create empty dictionary to be populated with keys and values
di = {}
#iterate key table with a search cursor
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (keyTab, [keyTabKeyFld, keyTabValFld]) as curs:
    for key, val in curs:
        #update dictionary
        di [key] = val

#update table with new values by use of an update cursor
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (updateTab, [updateTabValFld, updateTabUpdateFld]) as curs:
    for val, up in curs:
        #create new row with dictionary value
        row = (val, di [val])
        #update row
        curs.updateRow (row)
```